# In Android, why the aar files can speed up compilation

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android, why  the aar files can speed up compilation

I guess maybe because the content in aar file already compiled or it has the cache of compilation result

Comment: Speed it up compared to what?  Your question doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

**AAR** files are more similar to **Jars** than to **Dlls** for the following reason:

> Dlls can be shared across applications where as AARs and jars are
>   packaged in with your app.

**AARs** vs **Jars**:

> The main difference between a Jar and a AAR is that AARs include
>   resources such as layouts, drawables etc. This makes it a lot easier
>   to create self-contained visual components. For example if you have
>   multiple apps that use the same login screen, with Jars you could
>   share classes but not the layout, styles, etc., you still had to
>   duplicate them. With AARs everything is bundled in one neat package.

In conclusion, AARs are a big step in the right direction.

**Note:**
Similar attempts were made with apk-libs but they are now obsolete as AARs are much better.

Answer (score 0):

Because it can include everything needed to build an app, including source code, resource files, and an Android manifest. However, instead of compiling into an APK that runs on a device, an Android library compiles into an Android Archive (AAR) file that you can use as a dependency for an Android app module.